# How to send a custom email with an attached report based on variables with MS Access? 2003 or 2007

Tags: email, ms-access, pdf, report

I would need to send an email with standard text (but some custom parts like names and dates) with an attached pdf report generated with ms access. I prefer a solution for access 2003, but if it works on 2007 it's fine too.

Can be done directly from ms-access or I need some other apps/work?

thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several articles that might come in handy to help you with this.

Creating PDF files from within Access
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/pdffiles.htm

Report To PDF
http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm

Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=161088